# Custom JavaScript Variable showing multiple item in shopping cart

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to create a custom javascript variable to grab all the items in shopping cart.
I would like to have the variable return in below format:
item0 - item1 - item2

```
 function() { 
        prod_names = []; 

    for( var i=0; i<cart.itemCount; i++ ) { 
        prod_names.push(cart.items[i].name); 
    } 
    return prod_names.join(" - "); 
}
```

I used the code (edited: deleted the `.` above thanks to the reminders in the comments) but it returned undefined. Would like to seek help from all GTM experts on this situation. Thanks.

Below shows the datalayer elements in the page. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How are you invoking that anonymous function?

Comment: `cart.items.[i].name` <= looks like a typo with the `.` before the bracket notation.

Comment: Even when I delete the . before the bracket, the custom javascript variable doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that was your only issue, but I'm 99% it *is an issue*.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a `.` before `[]`

```js
function() { 
        prod_names = []; 

    for( var i=0; i<cart.itemCount; i++ ) { 
        prod_names.push(cart.items/* here is your problem --> */./* <-- */[i].name); 
    } 
    return prod_names.join(" - "); 
}
```

I personaly would do this like this:

```js
const getNames = cart => cart.items.map(item => item.name).join('-')
```

Comment: Sorry, may I know how to return it to a function / code to the variable configuration for your `getNames` recommendation? Thanks

Comment: It's just a function
`const names = getName(cart)`